# Looking to change order of stats shown

Tags: php

I tried combining as suggested in a previous link but Im still getting a error. I am fairly new to php so that is why i have two querys.

**Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/vhockey/public_html/vhatest/connect.php on line 88**

The table is "season12" and the table is "p"

Here is my connect.php file except server info...

```
function index_team_stats($subconference) {
$return = array();

$query = "SELECT id, teamname, teamnameseason, teamabr 
            FROM teams 
            WHERE subconference = '" . $subconference . "' 
            ORDER BY teamnameseason";

$teams = result_array($query);
foreach ($teams as $team) 
{
    $query = "SELECT gp, w, l, ol, p 
                FROM season12 
                WHERE team = '" . $team['teamnameseason'] . "' 
                ORDER BY p DESC 
                LIMIT 0,20'; ";

    $results = result_array($query);

    if ($results)
    {
        $results[0]['team'] = str_replace($team['teamnameseason'], '', $team['teamname']);
        $results[0]['teamabr'] = $team['teamabr'];
        $results[0]['teamid'] = $team['id'];
        $return[] = $results[0];
    }
}
return $return;
}




function get_team_name($teamnameseason) {



$query = "SELECT teamname FROM teams WHERE teamnameseason = '" . $teamnameseason . "'";



$row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));



return str_replace($teamnameseason, '', $row[0]);



}



function result_array($query) {



$results = mysql_query($query) or die("error on: " . $query . " saying: " . mysql_error());



$return = array();



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {



    $return[] = $row;



}



return $return;



}
```

Here is an image of the info ![All info sorted by team PTS from highest to lowest

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCBuF.png]

Should show Penguins, FLyers, Islanders, Rangers, Devils..

Comment: I would combine those 2 sql queries into one using a JOIN.

Comment: is `result_array` a user function? or you mixed up with `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN. An example is below. You may need to tweak based on your specific needs.

```
SELECT teams.id, teams.teamname, teams.teamnameseason, teams.teamabr, season12.gp,
    season12.w, season12.l, season12.ol, season12.p
FROM teams, season12
INNER JOIN season12
ON teams.teamname=season12.team
WHERE teams.subconference = '$subconference'
ORDER BY season12.p
LIMIT 0,20
```

Please note this code is not tested and may require modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php sort function http://php.net/usort

```
$callback = new function ($el1, $el2) {
    if ($el1['points'] == $el2['points']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($el1['points'] < $el2['points']) ? -1 : 1;  
}
$sorted_result = usort($results, $callback);
```